# Migrating from OAuthConfig in Fusion Table CRUD

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth, google-fusion-tables

I am using [Ferris Argyle’s CRUD](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/09/using-fusion-tables-with-apps-script.html) from the Google Apps Developers Blog to access a Fusion table.  Unfortunately, OAuth 1.0 was shut down on April 20th, 2015 and I need to update the script’s authorization method.

I think there are two choices - Migrate from OAuthConfig to the [OAuth1 library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/migration/oauth-config) or instead use the [OAuth2 for Apps Script library](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2).  The OAuth1 library looks simpler to implement but i’m not sure it will still work with Fusion tables.  OAuth2 looks like a more complicated solution and I don’t know how to configure it for anonymous access.  What is the best solution for a novice programer?

in-other-words, can a Fusion Table use OAuth1 library and, if not, is there an example of anonymous access for OAuth2?

Thanks,  Scott

EDIT: [Changes to OAuth in Apps Scripts](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2015/03/changes-to-oauth-in-apps-script.html) was helpful.

This is also provided direction - [Authenticate application with OAuth to access Fusion Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271623/authenticate-application-with-oauth-to-access-fusion-tables).

I think that OAuth2 as a service account (2LO) is the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you shouldn't need OAuth at all to get to Fusion Tables from an Apps Script.

Take a look at [this project](https://cdn.rawgit.com/fusiontable-gallery/fusion-tables-api-samples/master/FusionTablesSheetSync/docs/reference.html) that replaces the contents of a table with the data from a spreadsheet. Apps Script makes auth really simple.